# Maintain Logging in PHP

Tags: php, logging, phpunit, codeception

Is there any way to maintain loggs in PHP? I know about error logs but What I want to monitor the complete requests and response of my application? Or I just have to rely on error logs?
Any way to maintain the logs using [Code Ception](http://codeception.com/) OR [PHP Unit](https://phpunit.de/)

Comment: most php apps are web-hosted, so request are easy: look at the webserver's access_log. response, probably not - the log would be *HUGE* for any moderately busy site that spits out dynamic data.

Comment: you can add your own logging, and log what ever you need\want to

Comment: check this project https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Answer (score -1):

You can use the php function syslog() which us used to generate a system log entry. The syntax is...

```
bool syslog(int $priority, string $message);
```

The priority is a combination of the facility and level. The possible predefined values according to PHP are...

- LOG_EMERG
- LOG_ALERT
- LOG_CRIT
- LOG_ERR
- LOG_WARNING
- LOG_NOTICE
- LOG_INFO
- LOG_DEBUG

You can see more information on using syslog on the [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php)

Comment: Syslog should be used for logging messages that concern the system. I don't think is a good idea to clutter it with requests and responses data.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this answer would have been downvoted given the fact that from what I can tell I answered the question fully, and provided a documented solution. I would like to know so that I can improve my answers in the future, thanks.